# regex pattern to find full stop, exclamation mark or question mark in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm a newbie to regex. Here's the pattern that I could think of :

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[.!?]");`

Because the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/) says `[abc]  a, b, or c (simple class)` . But I'm wrong somehow. :-(

Comment: Well, you're missing an exclamation point, and adding a forward slash, for two things.

Comment: Oops.... :-| Deserve a downvote :-|

Comment: Could you post an example where this does not work? How are you using your pattern? With a matcher?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Yes, with a `Matcher` .

Comment: Yes, that pattern will match a period, exclamation mark, or question mark.  Would you like us to guess about the rest of your code to figure out why it's not working for you?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet well, I guess then there's some other mistake in my code. Should I post it as well? But it won't be relevant to the question anymore, because the regex pattern is not an issue anymore.

Comment: @Dmitri please refer to the above comment. :-)

Comment: It's OK, the point is to help you with your problem, the question title can always be cleaned up if necessary.

Comment: @Dmitri I'll better post a new question. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[.!?]");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher("Hello?World!...");
        while (m.find()) {
            System.err.println(m.group());
        }
    }

}
```

So what is your issue more precisely?

Comment: I guess then there's some other issue with my code. Should I post it? But it won't be relevant to the question anymore.

Comment: Yes, put another question then and put up some code. The best solution is to put an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) just like I did in this question. It removed all ambiguity and sometimes by writing it you will actually find your original error